# Facebook Unity SDK 5.2 still missing?

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

as far as i understood, there was... at a time, a link to download facebook unity sdk in version 5.2? But clearly, this link disappeared?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads/?campaign_id=282184128580929&placement=SDK_list

I know it was buggy, but i found a link to a fix.

https://github.com/Kabe0/Facebook-Unity-Fix

Does anyone has this unity package saved somewhere and could share it with the community?

I know its not perfect but at least i could start to implement the new version API to my game, or does anyone know when the sdk would be released?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in fact, despite the fix

https://github.com/Kabe0/Facebook-Unity-Fix

this zip file also contains the 5.2 build.

It appears that 5.1 is completely buggy regarding API.Feed 
And 5.2 is even worse.

I'm afraid we have to wait for 5.3, but unfortunately, no date is announced yet (and we are in middle of july as i'm writing those lines)

Regards
Pascal

Answer (score 0):

Yea not sure why they pulled that version. The version contained mostly new features so something must have been wrong with them. I updated the latest version as soon as I saw version 5.2 come out but about a week later facebook pulled it. So far it has caused me no issues so I never reverted the repo.

That fix is only for the keyhash problem facebook has where it relies on the debug keyhash while if you define one in your publish settings for unity it uses that key instead.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as i mentioned above, the fix contains the 5.2 build. But Facebook.dll contains some error that avoid project to even start...

Comment: I just reverted the repo verison to 5.1 as the bug you experienced was related to a broken lib file which is the reason Facebook pulled that build.